# PHP Generating time slots based on multilevel date time array

Tags: php, arrays

I have tried to find an answer everywhere on Google but couldn't find a match which looks like my problem.
I'm currently developing an appointment system, where the data comes from an external system.

In my system, it's possible to select "products" and quantity. So here's an example of selected products:
A0004 2x (appointment length = 10 minutes so 20 minutes in total)
A0010 1x (appointment length = 5 minutes)

The API from the external system requires that I request the available dates and times by product. So when I do that I have an array with the 2 products and their availability. Example:
(The datetimes are actually timestamps but I wanted to make it more visual in this example)

```
Array
(
    [A0004] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30-10-2014 09:20:00
            [1] => 30-10-2014 09:30:00
            [2] => 30-10-2014 15:20:00
            [3] => 30-10-2014 15:30:00
            [4] => 30-10-2014 16:30:00
            [5] => 30-10-2014 17:10:00
            [6] => 30-10-2014 17:20:00
            [7] => 30-10-2014 17:30:00
            [8] => 30-10-2014 18:10:00
            [9] => 30-10-2014 18:20:00
            [10] => 30-10-2014 18:30:00
            [11] => 31-10-2014 09:00:00
            [12] => 31-10-2014 09:10:00
            [13] => 31-10-2014 09:20:00
            [14] => 31-10-2014 12:20:00
            [15] => 03-11-2014 09:10:00
            [16] => 03-11-2014 09:20:00
            [17] => 03-11-2014 09:30:00
            [18] => 03-11-2014 10:10:00
            [19] => 03-11-2014 10:20:00
            [20] => 03-11-2014 12:10:00
            [21] => 03-11-2014 12:20:00
            [22] => 03-11-2014 12:30:00
            [23] => 03-11-2014 13:00:00
            [24] => 03-11-2014 13:10:00
            [25] => 03-11-2014 13:20:00
            [26] => 03-11-2014 14:00:00
            [27] => 03-11-2014 14:10:00
            [28] => 03-11-2014 14:20:00
            [29] => 03-11-2014 14:30:00
            [30] => 03-11-2014 15:10:00
            [31] => 03-11-2014 15:20:00
            [32] => 03-11-2014 15:30:00
            [33] => 03-11-2014 16:00:00
            [34] => 03-11-2014 16:10:00
            [35] => 03-11-2014 16:20:00
            [36] => 03-11-2014 16:30:00
            [37] => 03-11-2014 17:00:00
            [38] => 03-11-2014 17:10:00
            [39] => 03-11-2014 17:20:00
        )
    [A0010] => Array
        (
            [0] => 29-10-2014 15:15:00
            [1] => 29-10-2014 15:40:00
            [2] => 29-10-2014 16:35:00
            [3] => 29-10-2014 16:40:00
            [4] => 29-10-2014 17:10:00
            [5] => 29-10-2014 17:15:00
            [6] => 29-10-2014 17:20:00
            [7] => 29-10-2014 17:40:00
            [8] => 30-10-2014 09:20:00
            [9] => 30-10-2014 09:25:00
            [10] => 30-10-2014 09:30:00
            [11] => 30-10-2014 09:35:00
            [12] => 30-10-2014 09:40:00
            [13] => 30-10-2014 10:10:00
            [14] => 30-10-2014 10:25:00
            [15] => 30-10-2014 10:40:00
            [16] => 30-10-2014 11:05:00
            [17] => 30-10-2014 11:40:00
            [18] => 30-10-2014 12:25:00
            [19] => 30-10-2014 12:40:00
            [20] => 30-10-2014 13:40:00
            [21] => 30-10-2014 14:10:00
            [22] => 30-10-2014 14:40:00
            [23] => 30-10-2014 15:20:00
            [24] => 30-10-2014 15:25:00
            [25] => 30-10-2014 15:30:00
            [26] => 30-10-2014 15:35:00
            [27] => 30-10-2014 15:40:00
            [28] => 30-10-2014 16:15:00
            [29] => 30-10-2014 16:20:00
            [30] => 30-10-2014 16:30:00
            [31] => 30-10-2014 16:35:00
            [32] => 30-10-2014 16:40:00
            [33] => 30-10-2014 17:10:00
            [34] => 30-10-2014 17:15:00
            [35] => 30-10-2014 17:20:00
            [36] => 30-10-2014 17:25:00
            [37] => 30-10-2014 17:30:00
            [38] => 30-10-2014 17:35:00
            [39] => 30-10-2014 17:40:00
            [40] => 30-10-2014 18:05:00
            [41] => 30-10-2014 18:10:00
            [42] => 30-10-2014 18:15:00
            [43] => 30-10-2014 18:20:00
            [44] => 30-10-2014 18:25:00
            [45] => 30-10-2014 18:30:00
            [46] => 30-10-2014 18:35:00
            [47] => 30-10-2014 18:40:00
            [48] => 30-10-2014 19:15:00
            [49] => 30-10-2014 20:40:00
            [50] => 31-10-2014 09:00:00
            [51] => 31-10-2014 09:05:00
            [52] => 31-10-2014 09:10:00
            [53] => 31-10-2014 09:15:00
            [54] => 31-10-2014 09:20:00
            [55] => 31-10-2014 09:25:00
            [56] => 31-10-2014 09:40:00
            [57] => 31-10-2014 10:25:00
            [58] => 31-10-2014 10:35:00
            [59] => 31-10-2014 11:35:00
            [60] => 31-10-2014 11:40:00
            [61] => 31-10-2014 12:20:00
            [62] => 31-10-2014 12:25:00
            [63] => 03-11-2014 09:05:00
            [64] => 03-11-2014 09:10:00
            [65] => 03-11-2014 09:15:00
            [66] => 03-11-2014 09:20:00
            [67] => 03-11-2014 09:25:00
            [68] => 03-11-2014 09:30:00
            [69] => 03-11-2014 09:35:00
            [70] => 03-11-2014 09:40:00
            [71] => 03-11-2014 10:05:00
            [72] => 03-11-2014 10:10:00
            [73] => 03-11-2014 10:15:00
            [74] => 03-11-2014 10:20:00
            [75] => 03-11-2014 10:25:00
            [76] => 03-11-2014 10:40:00
            [77] => 03-11-2014 11:25:00
            [78] => 03-11-2014 11:40:00
            [79] => 03-11-2014 12:05:00
            [80] => 03-11-2014 12:10:00
            [81] => 03-11-2014 12:15:00
            [82] => 03-11-2014 12:20:00
            [83] => 03-11-2014 12:25:00
            [84] => 03-11-2014 12:30:00
            [85] => 03-11-2014 12:35:00
            [86] => 03-11-2014 12:40:00
            [87] => 03-11-2014 13:00:00
            [88] => 03-11-2014 13:05:00
            [89] => 03-11-2014 13:10:00
            [90] => 03-11-2014 13:15:00
            [91] => 03-11-2014 13:20:00
            [92] => 03-11-2014 13:25:00
            [93] => 03-11-2014 13:35:00
            [94] => 03-11-2014 13:40:00
            [95] => 03-11-2014 14:00:00
            [96] => 03-11-2014 14:05:00
            [97] => 03-11-2014 14:10:00
            [98] => 03-11-2014 14:15:00
            [99] => 03-11-2014 14:20:00
        )
)
1
```

With the information above I should generate a selection of timeslots where there is an appointment possible for these 2 products (3 in quantity).

A remark, it's possible to select more than 2 products and more than 2 quantity per product, so it has to be flexible.

So, in conclusion: Product A0004 has been selected twice so there has to be a timeslot in his availability of two consecutive times (20 minutes total), and the other product has to connect with that timeslot (before or after has to be possible). The end result has to be an array with available timeslots.

Does anyone have an idea on how I could get this to work? Especially with the flexibility of the quantity and amount of selected products.

Comment: And what did you tried so far?

Comment: Well that's the problem, I haven't really tried anything because first I have to have a plan on how to set this up. Tried something with a whole lot of foreaches but that immediately went out of memory and wasn't even flexibel (it only checked the first product and tried to find a consecutive timeslot from the other product, but that doesn't work with more than 2 products).